# Prove that $Gal(K/k) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

> Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of a finite field $k$. Prove that $Gal(K/k) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

From the definition in the book, here is how $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is defined:
Let $D = Cr(\mathbb{Z}_{p} | \; p \; prime)$, let $\delta: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow D$ be the map taking $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the vector with all coordinates equal to $x$. Then the group $D$ together with the map $\delta$ is the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, denoted $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

There seem to be many sources online that cite this result as true, but I'm having trouble finding anywhere that shows a proof. This question is from Profinite Groups (Wilson), so I doubt that the solution is all that straight-forward. Could anyone offer me a solution or perhaps some insight on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What is your definition of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$? $Gal(K/k)$ is given by $\lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, which is the definition of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ according to some.

Comment: $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the profinite completion of the integers. It might be worth mentioning that this chapter of the book is where the link between galois groups and profinite groups is first introduced.

Comment: More precisely: The group $D = Cr(\mathbb{Z}_{p} |\; p \; prime)$ together with the map $\delta: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow D$ is the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$. The map $\delta$ is the map taking $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the vector with all coordinates equal to $x$.

Comment: Sure, I know what $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ denotes. My point is that the profinite completion of a group $G$ is defined by some to be the inverse limit of $G/N$ over all normal subgroups $N$ of finite index, which is exactly what's written above. Does this agree with your definition?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what's meant by $Cr(\mathbb{Z}_{p} \mid p \text{ prime})$. Is this supposed to be the infinite product $\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ of all of the $p$-adic integers? Regardless, I think it'd be helpful if you updated your question with explicit definitions of the objects you are using.

Comment: It's the cartesian product of all $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ such that $p$ is prime. You're probably right, I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A detailed proof is, for example, given in James S. Milne's lecture notes on [Fields and Galois Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), EXAMPLE 7.16., page $97$. Ingredients are the canonical Frobenius element $\sigma:a\mapsto a^p$, the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, and the isomorphism $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\rightarrow Gal(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: Is it correct to start with $\rho = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma^{k_n }$ where $k_{n+1} \equiv k_n \bmod n!$ ?

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Milne’s given name is James.

Comment: @Lubin I apologize!

Answer (score 3):

For any field $k$ and a fixed algebraic closure $K$ of $k$, practically by definition, $K$ is the inductive (=direct) limit of its subextensions $L/k$ of finite degree. By (infinite) Galois theory, $Gal(K/k)$ is then the projective (=inverse) limit of its subgroups of finite index. If $k$ is a finite field,    for any integer $n$, we know that $K$ admits a unique subextension $L/k$ of degree $n$, and this extension is cyclic. Hence $Gal(K/k)$ is the projective limit of the $(Z/nZ, +)$, i.e. $(\hat Z, +)$ .